# Embedded subdocument query projection in mongoose, overriding a default schema {select: false}

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two Schemas as follow:

```
const threadSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {type: String, required: true},
  created_on: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
  bumped_on: {type: Date, default: new Date()},
  reported: {type: Boolean, default: false, select: false},
  delete_password: {type: String, required: true, select: false},
  replies: [replySchema],
  replycount: {type: Number, default: 0}
})

const messageBoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  threads: [threadSchema]
})
```

I'm trying to write a query that will retrieve the `thread.delete_password` field. The query below does what I expect, except that it *only includes the `delete_password` in the most recent thread added to the array*. Presumably it has something to do with the property being set to `select: false` in the schema, but that doesn't tell me much.

**EDIT: if I `.push()` each new thread into the `messageBoard.threads` array instead of using `.unshift()` like I was originally, the `delete_password` is indeed retrieved for all threads. I'm dying to understand what is going on here.**

```
let query = await MessageBoard.aggregate([
        { $match: { name: board } },
        { $unwind: '$threads' },
        { $project: { 'threads.delete_password': 1, 'threads.text': 1 } }
      ]);
```

An example output looks like this:

```
 {
    _id: new ObjectId("2358244s918f81398y334819"),
    threads: { text: 'test', delete_password: 'password' }
  }
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("647403375f2cf8284cd9c601"),
    threads: { text: 'test' }
  },
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("15836197d7193874dc3s897"),
    threads: { text: 'test' }
  }
```

I'm at a loss.